# Missing icon with gnome-recipes

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, titlebar

I am a bit lost with the gnome-recipes title bar missing an icon in my VM compared to the host system, both running Ubuntu 19.10 (though desktop is an upgrade when VM is a fresh install) and Gnome-recipes 2.0.2-5.
Host :
[image: Host title bar : the "wheel icon" is present]

And this is how it displays in my VM :
[image: no "wheel icon" when in the VM]

As I said, I am running same OS version, same App version, same theme, etc... I have no idea why  such diffrence. And that icon allows you to import recipes, which what I would to test in the VM, after building debug env, as Gnome-recipes crash when inserting xml file (from Gourmet).

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: You say "both running Ubuntu 19.04" but you put the "19.10" tag.

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides`?

Comment: Was empty, tried "{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>}" (as on my desktop) but no change.